# How to prevent position jumps in a network game?

Tags: networking, udp, lag

I'm using a .net based game engine and an intermediate program (using reliable udp) to handle the position and rotation transfer. The data seems to transfer correctly but there are jumps between transfered positions (probably from network lag). I've tried easing the position but that didn't work as the next position comes rather late. What can I do to prevent or decrease this effect?

I would also appreciate some implementations using .net (preferably c#) on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interpolation and extrapolation are the things you should be looking at. 
take a look at;
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading a great article about [the networking architecture in the Unreal Engine](http://unreal.epicgames.com/Network.htm). A simple thing I would try first is simulating the world in between network frames so that the world clock is independent of the network timing. I guess the big catch is commiting to a big change, like killing a player – it’s a bummer to simulate player being hit only to receive a network update that says the player managed to dodge the bullet. It’s been a while since I read the linked article, but I believe you will find the details there.